# Evaporation occurring throughout

Tags: evaporation

Do liquid and gaseous molecules coexist below the surface of a pure substance at temperatures below the liquid's boiling point temperature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although the terminology in your title is not quite correct. The answer is found in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling). It says:

> Evaporation only happens on the surface while boiling happens throughout the liquid. When a liquid reaches its boiling point bubbles of gas form in it which rise into the surface and burst into the air. This process is called boiling.

In other words (as it says elsewhere in the article) some particles below the surface temporarily gain enough energy to be a gas, but this doesn't have any appreciable effect until you reach the boiling point, when bubbles begin to form so the gas can escape. With evaporation, particles on the surface gain high energy, and they are able to escape the liquid because they are on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

No. The confusion stems from the terminology. A single molecule can not be "liquid" or "gaseous". Instead, it is in the liquid or gas phase. To be in the gas phase requires that its local density is small. If this happens in a liquid, the gaseous bubbles have a lower density and rise to the surface. This is the definition of "boiling" and means you are at/above the boiling point ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling)).

Below the boiling point, you will find molecules with high kinetic energies. But their local environment will still be a liquid and they will still experience hydrodynamic effects.